# Include model in robot URDF

Tags: urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have downloaded a model of a kinect with functioning plugins. How can I add this model into my existing urdf?
Thanks,
L

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262610/include-model-in-robot-urdf/) by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 285 on 2017-05-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2017-05-26**:
You likely want to be looking to [xacro](http://wiki.ros.org/xacro). This has the ability to include other URDF and/or xacro files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In general you will want to make a xacro for your composite system (i.e., robots, sensors, environment, etc.).  In the industrial world this is equivalent to your workcell.  The ROS-Industrial guys have a training unit on creating modular xacro macros for building workcells [here](https://github.com/ros-industrial/industrial_training/wiki/Workcell-XACRO).  Good macros will accept parent links and relative offsets for easily building configurations.

As an example, you might end up with something that looks like the following for you high-level macro that will create your desired configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<robot name="my_robot" xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">
    <xacro:include filename="$(find my_robot_support)/urdf/awesome_robot_macro.xacro"/>
    <xacro:include filename="$(find my_sensor_a_support)/urdf/sensor_a_macro.xacro"/>
    <xacro:include filename="$(find my_sensor_b_support)/urdf/sensor_b_macro.xacro"/>

    <xacro:property name="pi" value="3.141592"/>

    <!-- the robot -->
    <xacro:awesome_robot />
    
    <!-- my sensor A (mounted to the table) -->
    <xacro:sensor_a parent_link="$base_link" 
        x_val="0.400" y_val="0.500" z_val="0.000"
        roll="0.000" pitch="0.000" yaw="1.200"/> 

    <!-- my sensor B (mounted to the robot's tool flange) -->
    <xacro:sensor_b parent_link="$tool0" 
        x_val="0.000" y_val="0.000" z_val="0.000"
        roll="${pi/2}" pitch="0.000" yaw="${-pi}"/> 

    ....

</robot>
```

---

Originally posted by [BrettHemes](https://answers.ros.org/users/20527/bretthemes/) with karma: 525 on 2017-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-26**:
An alternative pattern would be to create the connecting `link`s and `joint`s *outside* the xacro macros (ie: at the top-level level). That removes the need for those additional parameters and increases visibility of the connecting structures.